# Convexity of a subset is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $V$ be the set of sequences whose terms are contained in $\mathbb{R}^n . 
V$ is the set of functions $x(·) : N → \mathbb{R}^n $ which we denote as $\{x_n\}_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. $V$ is a vector space.
$V_0 \subset V$ consists of all convergent sequences, ie:

$V_0 := \{\{x_n \}_n ∈ V : \exists \space \space x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n  | x = lim_{n→∞} x_n \}$

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and
$V(A):= \{\{x_n\}_n \in V_0 : lim_{n→∞}x_n \in A\}$

***Prove that if $A$ is convex, then $V(A)$ is convex***

I am struggling to prove this, and also cannot interpret what is meant by $\{\{x_n\}_n$ ?
and what $V(A)$ is.

Is $V(A)$ simply the set of the convergent sequences $\{x_n\}_n$ which converge in the set $A$?

Comment: Yes! $V(A)$ is just the set of those sequences which converge and have their limits in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, what about $t x_n + (1-t) y_n$?

Comment: then $$tx_n + (1-t)y_n \to tx + (1-t)y \in A$$
since $A$ is convex, 

and $\forall t \in [0,1]$ $$tx + (1-t)y \subset V(A)$$ 
$\therefore V(A)$ is also convex?

Comment: you mean the right thing, but your notation is wrong. You mean $\forall t\in[0,1]:tx+(1-t)y\color{red}{\in A}$

Comment: @sranthrop thanks, is that because we have to show that the line is in $V(A)$, rather than a subset? Can the line not be classified as subset of a larger set? What is the precise difference between the two, if you dont mind explaining

Comment: What you have to show is that if $(x_n)\in V(A)$ and $(y_n)\in V(A)$ with the respective limits $x$ and $y$, then $(tx_n+(1-t)y_n)\in V(A)$ for each $t\in[0,1]$. You have shown that $tx_n+(1-t)y_n\to tx+(1-t)y$, so $(tx_n+(1-t)y_n)\in V_0$, and since $tx+(1-t)y\in A$ for each $t$ we have that $(tx_n+(1-t)y_n)\in V(A)$.